# SlickGrid: Slick.CellRangeDecorator is not a constructor

Tags: ajax, constructor, slickgrid

I have just started using SlickGrid and was hoping someone can help me solve this issue.
I am following the example file and simple trying to load my own table content using ajax. 
I keep getting this error though:

> Slick.CellRangeDecorator is not a constructor

I have Googled it and it is not coming up anywhere else. I was thinking it might have something to do with the way the files are being references, i.e. maybe the wrong file paths were being called, but Firebug is showing that all files are being called successfully.

If anyone can help that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get the latest SlickGrid (2.0 alpha as of today) from the trunk and test "example3-editing.html", you should see the same error. The error occurs because "example3-editing.html" is missing a reference to the cellrangedecorator.js file and can be fixed by adding:

```
    <script src="../plugins/slick.cellrangedecorator.js"></script>
```

in that file.

Could you please try copying your html file in the example directory, then ensure that the cellrangedecorator.js script is indeed included using the above declaration and let us know if that fixes the issue?